# Rails migration error: Unicode string return null value inside "execute >> SQL"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, unicode

I'm trying to do the things below in migration.

1. Split "Name" as splitted_name array.
2. SET first_name as splitted_name[0].
3. SET last_name as splitted_name[-1] if the splitted_name[0] and splitted_name[-1] were differnt.
4. SET last_name as empty string if the splitted_name[0] and splitted_name[1] are same.

Here is the code.

```
class ConvertNameIntoFirstAndLastName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      DO
      $do$
      DECLARE
        u record;
      BEGIN
      FOR u IN SELECT * FROM users LOOP
        DECLARE
          splitted_name text[];
        BEGIN
          splitted_name := CASE WHEN u.name IS NULL THEN '{''}'
                                ELSE regexp_split_to_array(u.name, E'\\s+')
                           END;
          UPDATE users
            SET 
              first_name = splitted_name[0],
              last_name = CASE WHEN splitted_name[0] = splitted_name[-1] THEN ''
                               ELSE splitted_name[-1]
                          END,
              name = splitted_name[0] || ' ' || (CASE WHEN splitted_name[0] = splitted_name[-1] THEN '{''}'
                                                      ELSE splitted_name[-1]
                                                END)
          WHERE id = u.id;
        END;
      END LOOP;
      END;
      $do$;
    SQL
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

The problem is u.name always return null when the name is unicode characters. The database encoding is set as Unicode.

Here is the error message.

PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
=> The name is actually not null but some Unicode string.

Do you have any idea what is the cause of this error and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was so naive that I didn't know that I should use splitted_name[1] for the first_name and there's no array[-1].

This code worked.

```
class ConvertNameIntoFirstAndLastName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      DO
      $do$
      DECLARE
        u record;
      BEGIN
      FOR u IN SELECT * FROM users LOOP
        DECLARE
          splitted_name text[];
        BEGIN
          splitted_name := regexp_split_to_array(regexp_replace(u.name, '　', ' '), ' ');
          UPDATE users
            SET 
              first_name = splitted_name[1],
              last_name = CASE WHEN splitted_name[1] = splitted_name[array_upper(splitted_name, 1)] THEN ''
                               ELSE splitted_name[array_upper(splitted_name, 1)]
                          END,
              name = splitted_name[1] || ' ' || (CASE WHEN splitted_name[1] = splitted_name[array_upper(splitted_name, 1)] THEN ''
                                                      ELSE splitted_name[array_upper(splitted_name, 1)]
                                                END)
          WHERE id = u.id;
        END;
      END LOOP;
      END;
      $do$;
    SQL
  end

  def down
  end
end
```